# mouseUp instead of click firing on <button> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, jquery-events

My jQuery file upload plugin is not willing to perform a delete operation on some listed files.

The problem is that when I click a delete `<button>`, a delegated event doesn't get fired.

I have been trying to debug it with Chrome visual tools for JS debugging and have stumbled upon a clue. In a working plugin page demo, the `click` event is bound on a button element:

[image]

But in my case, even though that the "delegation" code is absolutely the same, I have tbody.file "listening" for `button` event, not `click`:

[image]

Why in one case a `click` even is linked to, and in the other - a `button` event. What is a `button` event anyway?

Additional info:

The plugin that is doing an event delegation is [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) and the code that binds events in both cases is:

```
_initEventHandlers: function () {
            parentWidget.prototype._initEventHandlers.call(this);
            var eventData = {fileupload: this};
            this.options.filesContainer
                .delegate(
                    '.start button',
                    'click.' + this.options.namespace,
                    eventData,
                    this._startHandler
                )
                .delegate(
                    '.cancel button',
                    'click.' + this.options.namespace,
                    eventData,
                    this._cancelHandler
                )
                .delegate(
                    '.delete button',
                    'click.' + this.options.namespace,
                    eventData,
                    this._deleteHandler
                );
            this._initButtonBarEventHandlers();
        },
```

The value of `this.options.namespace` is 'fileupload' in both working and a problem scenarios.

When I pause a JS execution and click the button, I see that the `mouseup` event get's called, instead of a click, and the target is the `document`. Event source is a span inside a `button` element.

Comment: How can we possibly help you without knowing what plugin you're using and how you implemented it...

Comment: Looks as if a custom event has been inadvertently specified. Try searching your source for something like `.on('button'` (could be single of double quotes).

Comment: I've updated the question with additional info. And I have also tried replacing `.delegate` with `.on` at no success.

Comment: Thinking out loud .... Does the *jQuery-File-Upload* documentation state any constraints with regard to jQuery version?  ..... That type of `.delegate()` syntax, needs jQuery 1.4.3+ and `.on()` needs 1.7+ ..... When you tried `.on()` did you remember to swap the first two arguments of delegate in each case? ..... If you alert out `'click.' + this.options.namespace` at the top of `_initEventHandlers: function () {` does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for debugging vectors! =) I have been using jQ 1.7.2 all along. And did swap the params when checked `.on` approach. When trying alert('click.' + this.options.namespace); it alerts-out "click.fileupload". Whenever I pause the scripts on the page and click the button, I am able to see the MouseEven data that occurs. In a working example it is a 'click' event with an eventSource of HTMLButtonElement, whereas in my problem case - it is 'mouseUp' with a HTMLSpanElement. Span here is a text span within an html button tag.